# Parent Game Object to Follow Child

Tags: unity-game-engine

Is there a way to have a parent object follow the combined bounds box of the child objects?

I have child objects which I apply force to for movement (via `AddForceAtPosition). The problem is that they leave the parent behind in world space. I understand that children are relative to the parents position. But is there anything I can do to address this?

I'd really like to keep to keep the force being applied to the child object's rigid bodies as it gives me the physics behaviour I need.

I have experimented with getting the bounds of all child objects, then setting the transform of the parent to the children. But this causes jittery behaviour since moving the parent also moves the children.

Comment: Perhaps you could connect them via [joints](https://docs.unity3d.com/2020.1/Documentation/Manual/Joints.html)? It's hard to say anything more specific without additional details about your code/requirements.

Comment: why are those objects nested/parented at all then?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of doing this, the best way is to change the structure following:

```
A (parent)
  B (child 1)
  C (child 2)
```

to:

```
Root (new parent with nothing on it)
  A (old parent)
  B (old child 1)
  C (old child 2)
```

Then move A the way you tried before. You might also want to look into [Joints](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Joints.html), and see if this might suit your need better. If you don't want two colliders to interact with each other, you might also want to look into [Layer Based Collision Detection](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LayerBasedCollision.html) and [Physics.IgnoreCollision()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.IgnoreCollision.html).

An alternative that I really wouldn't recommend, is counteracting the movement of the parent with the children. So whenever you move the parent you move the local position of the child you want to stay still the opposite amount. This however could possibly make your physics wonky.